# duplicate class found in dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

Duplicate class javax.annotation.Generated found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.PostConstruct found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.PreDestroy found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.Resource found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.Resource$AuthenticationType found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.Resources found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.security.DenyAll found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.security.PermitAll found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)
Duplicate class javax.annotation.security.RunAs found in modules jetified-javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2) and jetified-jsr250-api-1.0.jar (javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0)

```
 //Libraries 

  //    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.8.0')
   
  
         //    compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech')
```

Comment: Did you try putting android.enableJetifier=true in your gradle.properties file?

Comment: yes @NikhilJain

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @AhsanAli?